# Fluid mesh disappears when I save

Tags: mesh, fluid-simulation

I am brand new to Blender and this is the first project I've made. I am using 2.83. I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zOjJfc6ZJI to make a fluid fill a container.

Yesterday I baked my data and my mesh and everything seemed to look as it should. I saved this project with multiple versions each time, 5 to be exact. I could close the file and reopen it and everything still looked correct. Last night my computer died of low battery, however, I knew my files were saved, and I was going to save rendering for today. Now that I opened the file today, my fluid looks totally wrong

The fluid and its color is still there but it now fills the container in a weird way:

[image: the fluid and its color is still there but it now fills the container in a weird way]

When I am in the solid view and I move through my timeline I see no particle data and no mesh at all. When I am in the render view it looks as it does in the attached picture. Everything is in this weird oval shape and there is no movement. I've also attached how things should look as in the tutorial. This is how it looked for me yesterday:

[image: the water flows out and fills the container]

I am not sure how to fix this other than freeing the data and baking it all again.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the fluid simulation settings, go into the **Cache** menu. Inside of it there should be a file path. This will lead to the location where your fluid data is stored in.

Navigate to the folder where the **Cache** says the data is. Inside that folder, look for more folders titled with names like **Data, Mesh, Config** as those are the folder names that Blender uses to store fluid sim data. If you are able to find these folders and they have files inside, then you have a problem because Blender is not reading them. Double-check the file paths.

If they don't exist, then you have a problem because the fluid simulation files are gone. This is usually because if you do not specify a cache folder, then Blender finds a temporary space for it. On my computer, this temporary space is always cleared when it shuts down or restarts. This means you have to rebake everything again.

To avoid this problem in the future, always specify a cache folder in the cache menu before you bake anything.